# Java regular expression consider empty values

Tags: java, regex

I have some key value pairs as - key(value)

example data -

```
name(alex)
crimehistory
address(newland)
```

I am processing the data line by line and want to fetch the key value pairs. If value is not present it should be null (crimehistory).

My current regular expression is -

```
String pattern = "^(?<key>.*?)\\((?<value>.*)\\)";
```

But it gets me the key value only for name and address. What should I modify in the regular expression so that it gets me the key 'crimehistory' with null value  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the second part optional.

```
^(?<key>.*?)(?:\\((?<value>.*)\\))?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mY3zO8/1)